# Open huge text file and perform regex searching

Tags: python, regex, text-mining

I'm trying to open a huge text file (1 GB) and perform some text mining.
I'm willing to perform some regex searching.
When I'm using the read() function, I'm getting the error:

```
File "C:\Python33\lib\encodings\latin_1.py", line 26, in decode
return codecs.latin_1_decode(input,self.errors)[0]
MemoryError
```

My code is:

```
dataFile = open('data/AllData_2000001_3000000.txt', 'r', encoding="latin-1")
print(dataFile.read())
```

What will be the best way to open the text, in order to perform regex search?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on what you want to do:

If you really want to perform a regex search on the whole 1GB in one piece, you don't have a lot of options. Switching to 64-bit Python might be one if you're using a 32-bit version right now.

Is your text file organized in lines or something the like? In that case you can read one line, process it, go to the next and so on. Of course this works with any kind of 'chunk' that you can isolate.

Answer (score 5):

By doing `print(dataFile.read())` you're loading the whole file in memory, that's why you're getting the error. A better way to do it would be line by line:

```
dataFile = open('data/AllData_2000001_3000000.txt', 'r', encoding="latin-1")
for line in dataFile:
    #perform regex searching in each line here
    print(line)
```

Hope this helps!